# Access shortcut menu not saved on exit

Tags: vba, ms-access, shortcut

I use Access 2010  and create shortcut menu for right-click on reports.   Each time I exit the application and re-open my file, the right-click does not work, and en error message popups.

I could not find an explanation and solution anywhere about this.  May there be someone who may know the reason and a suggest a possible  solution?

BR,  Çağlar Durgun

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/create-a-shortcut-menu-for-a-form-form-control-or-report

Comment: Of course one way is to re-create the short-cut menu each time the application starts, as a work-around :(

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.add

Below is the format
CommandBars.Add (Name, Position, MenuBar, Temporary)

I've now realised that the example I've copied from learn.microsoft.com (the link in the question) had Temporary = True..!

Sorry for this,   issue is now resolved!   :)